# Creating a handlebars template in an external file

Tags: handlebars.js

My question is very simple although I couldn't find a way to do it.

I basically want to have all of my handlebars templates external. 
Here is a sample template file of mine. It is called `example.js`

```
<script id="test_template">
<div>Hello world!</div>
</script>
```

When I include it in the html file I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

For the first line - the browser isn't happy that there is some html in the javascript source file.

My qustion is: what way is there arround it / What is the standard ways to split templates into files in handlebars ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a file, add `type="text/x-handlebars-template"`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="test_template">
    <div>Hello world!</div>
</script>
```

For an external file, look:
https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/82